# How do I find constants so that the curvature of an oscillating funtion is between them?

Tags: calculus, curvature, parametrization

I am currently struggling with how to answer this question:

"Consider the planar curve $y = a\sin(bx)$ where $a, b$ are non-zero real
numbers. Find constants $A$ and $B$ so that $A \le k \le B$ for all $x$, where $k$ is the
curvature at $x$. These constants will be dependent on $a, b$"

I used the definition for curvature for a planar curve to get

$$k = \frac{|ab^2\sin(bx)|}{(1+(ab\cos(bx))^2)^{3/2}}$$

I know $\cos(bx)$ and $\sin(bx)$ oscillate but the curvature is always even, so I don't know what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting math equations (put $ on each side of the math). Also, please do not refer the question to a linked image, as not all users can see the image, and it is harder to find when searching.

Comment: Alright Edited it in.

Comment: The curvature of $y = a\sin bx$ should be expected to be even. Curvature is the inverse of the radius of the osculating circle ("kissing" circle). Because the sinusoid is symmetric through the origin, the osculating circles at the same distance from the origin will be identically sized even though one will be above the curve, while the other will be below. I haven't checked your math, but it at least passes unit analysis. The absolute value is troubling, as the function is analytic and $k$ should vary smoothly, but that is likely an artifact of needing the square root on the bottom.

Comment: Assuming your equation is correct, you can read the tightest possible bounds $A$ and $B$ on $k$ directly from it, just by knowing how $\sin$ and $\cos$ behave.